# Why does wrapping this in a function take 10x longer to run?

Tags: clojure

Can anyone explain why the time jumps by an order of magnitude simply by wrapping this in a function?

```
user> (time (loop [n 0 t 0]
              (if (= n 10000000)
                t
                (recur (inc n) (+ t n)))))
"Elapsed time: 29.312145 msecs"
49999995000000

user> (defn tl [r] (loop [n 0 t 0]
                    (if (= n r)
                      t
                      (recur (inc n) (+ t n)))))
#<Var@54dd6004: #object[user$eval3462$tl__3463 0x7d8ba46 "user$eval3462$tl__3463@7d8ba46"]>

user> (time (tl 10000000))
"Elapsed time: 507.333844 msecs"
49999995000000
```

I'm curious how a simply iteration like this can be made much faster. For example, a similar iterative loop in C++ takes less than 1 ms in Release mode, or about 20 ms in Debug mode on the same system as this Clojure code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because in second case passed argument is being boxed. Add type hint to fix this:

```
user> (defn tl [^long r]
  (loop [n 0 t 0]
    (if (= n r)
      t
      (recur (inc n) (+ t n)))))

user> (time (tl 10000000))
"Elapsed time: 20.268396 msecs"
49999995000000
```

UPD:

1, 2) In the first case you operate with java primitives, that's why it's so fast. `^Integer` won't work here, because it's type hint for boxed type `java.lang.Integer` (that's why it's capitalized). `^long` is type hint exactly for java `long` primitive. For function parameters you may do only `^long` and `^double` primitive type hints (<del>others are not supported</del> besides of these you may do type hints for all kinds of primitive arrays, like `^floats`, `^bytes` etc.).

3) Since passed argument is boxed this forces generic aritmethics for all operations. In other words, every `+` and `inc` operation will create new object on heap (in case of primitives, they will remain on stack).

UPD 2:

As an alternative to type hinting you may explicitly convert passed argument to primitive before the loop:

```
user> (defn tl [r]
  (let [r (long r)]
    (loop [n 0 t 0]
      (if (= n r)
        t
        (recur (inc n) (+ t n))))))

user> (time (tl 10000000))
"Elapsed time: 18.907161 msecs"
49999995000000
```

Comment: two followups: I had tried this with `^Integer` with no difference; why is `long` necessary for an arg of ten million? and 2) why is `long` lower-case but `^Integer` must be capitalized or won't compile? 3) since the arg is only passed once, at function call, this "unboxing"  one time only is enough to cause such a huge time increase?

Comment: @johnbakers I'll extend my answer